# Python script running from windows scheduled task is storing data in wrong folder

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I have a script that scrapes data, it saves it to my local db and it takes screenshot from webpages and stores it in a local folder. Both the db and screenshots folder are located in a folder on my Desktop.

Here are some lines of code from my script.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect('NW.db')

    if not os.path.exists('nw_' + req[1]):
        os.mkdir('nw_' + req[1])
    # folder = f'nw_{req[1]}\{Month}_{Hire_Start}'
    folder = f'nw_{req[1]}\{Hire_Start}'
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        os.mkdir(folder)

    folder_w = f'nw_{req[1]}'
    if not os.path.exists(folder_w):
        os.mkdir(folder_w)

ss.full_Screenshot(driver, save_path=r'.', image_name=folder + "NW_" + req[1] + "_" + days3 + "_" + Hire_Start + ".jpg")
```

Everything is working fine and it is stored in the same folder where I am running my script from. But when I make a windows scheduled task to run this script at a specific time it stores the db file and the screenshots folder in the following location **C:\Windows\System32** instead of my folder on the Desktop

I made a batch file and I added this to my scheduled task

```
"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Python_Kishen\NW_offer.py"
pause
```

[image: Screenshot windows scheduled task]

Comment: Use [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path): `sqlite3.connect(Path(__file__).with_name('NW.db'))`. Same using [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) functions: `sqlite3.connect(join(dirname(__file__), 'NW.db'))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on your "current" or "working" directory in a script run from the system. Specify the full path to where you want your output files.

You *can* use os.chdir() to make your preferred destination your current dir, but that's not the best way. Full paths.

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler process likely has a different location it operates from, and it looks like you're using relative paths.  I'd recommend using full paths if you have a place you want this all to go.  Then it doesn't matter where the code is run from.

As a side note, it looks like you're doing a lot of repeat string building.  Why not do that once and store the result in a variable?  Just use the variable in the few places you need that value.

Comment: Thx Kevin, will use full paths and check my code again